# Is there a way to convert a string, that was suppose to be stored as a vector, into a vector?

Tags: python, mfcc

I saved my mfcc data into a pandas data frame. My issue is that I saved it as type str when I would like to access it as a matrix of numbers.

```
i=0
for file in train_csv2['fname']:
signal, sr = librosa.load(file)
mfcc = librosa.feature.mfcc(signal, sr=sr,
                            n_mfcc=13, 
                            n_fft=2048, 
                            hop_length=512)
mfcc = mfcc.T
train_csv2.at[i, 'FFT'] = mfcc
i += 1
```

after running this code my dataframe train_csv2 has stored all of the values as strings. It took me 3.5 hours to run this due to the large amount of audio files I was using.

Is there a way to convert the string(s)...

```
[[-8.46002580e+00  7.08650460e-01 -1.35593844e+01 ... -9.93381115e+00\n  -3.62304403e+00  4.12729614e+00]\n [ 9.54518993e+00 -2.74505349e+00 -1.17114286e+01 ... -8.55533103e+00\n   1.88484478e-01  7.91402262e+00]\n [ 1.49292642e+01 -1.56909610e+01 -1.10280461e+01 ... -8.37234667e+00\n   9.35007917e+00  1.34211000e+01]\n ...\n [-6.22648700e+02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]\n [-6.22648700e+02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]\n [-6.22648700e+02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]
```

into a list/ vector?

Answer (score 1):

I tried the above method that @Nicolescu suggested, and with some tweeking it works! (It originally returned a list of empty lists)

Since you're running with a DataFrame I would suggest some changes to the answer above:

```
def clean_feat(input):    
    first_clean = input[1:len(input) - 1]
    second_clean = first_clean.replace('\n', '')
    last = second_clean.split()
    return_list = []
    for array in last:
        return_list.append([float(array)])
    return return_list

results = [clean_feat(x) for x in train_csv2['FFT']]
```

Hope that can help, and thank you Nicolescu Ionut Lucian for the original idea that helped me format my own code!

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 def test_1(self):
    input = '[[-8.46002580e+00  7.08650460e-01 -1.35593844e+01 -9.93381115e+00\n  -3.62304403e+00  4.12729614e+00]\n [ 9.54518993e+00 -2.74505349e+00 -1.17114286e+01 -8.55533103e+00\n   1.88484478e-01  7.91402262e+00]\n [ 1.49292642e+01 -1.56909610e+01 -1.10280461e+01 -8.37234667e+00\n   9.35007917e+00  1.34211000e+01]\n ...\n [-6.22648700e+02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]\n [-6.22648700e+02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]\n [-6.22648700e+02  0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00 ...  0.00000000e+00\n   0.00000000e+00  0.00000000e+00]]'
    first_clean = input[1:len(input) - 1]
    second_clean = first_clean.replace('\n', '')
    third_clean = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', second_clean)
    return_list = []
    for array in third_clean:
        return_list.append([float(arr) for arr in array.split(' ') if arr])
    return return_list
```